# El Capitan, codesign from command line: no identity found

Tags: xcode, osx-elcapitan, codesign

I am trying to resign my .dmg on El Capitan.

First, I got xcode 8.1.beta and installed to my el captain, then from xcode I did:

```
   xcode --> preferences-->accounts--> view Details --> create certificates--> Done (provisioning profiles part is empty, no idea what this is about).
```

Then from keychain Access--> login (certificates) --> I saw:

```
Apple WWDR certificate
Developer ID Application certificate
Developer ID Installer certificate
Developer ID Certification Authority
```

---

Then from the command line:

I did:

```
  certtool y | grep Developer\ ID
```

I got:

```
  Developer ID Certification Authority
  Developer ID Application: my company name
  Developer ID certification Authority
```

But when I did:

```
  codesign --verify --verbose --sign "Developer ID Application: my company name" *.dylib
```

I got:

> Developer ID Application: my company name: no identity found.

Answer (score 0):

Try finding the names of available and valid codesigning identities with:

```
security find-identity -p codesigning -v login.keychain
 Policy: Code Signing
  Matching identities
   ...
   3) 98786D82765110FCCAFE41E325B836C5EB3B9C91 "Developer ID Application: ABC"
```

Then use one of those exact results for codesign and also enforce the use of your login.keychain:

```
security list-keychains -d user -s login.keychain
security default-keychain -s login.keychain

codesign -vfs "Developer ID Application: ABC" --keychain login.keychain *.dylib
```